# Setup for Tor in school network

Tags: mac

I'm trying to use TorBrowser in my school network, however it is stuck establishing a connection: `Establishing a Tor circuit...`
This is using the connect option without any custom settings.

For clarity, I've tried multiple bridges which all fail. The error message is "`Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.`"

Here is the logs...

`27/03/2018, 11:29:10.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:29:10.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:29:10.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:29:10.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/03/2018, 11:29:10.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
27/03/2018, 11:30:19.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/03/2018, 11:30:19.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:30:19.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/03/2018, 11:30:19.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
27/03/2018, 11:30:20.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:30:20.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:30:20.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:30:20.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/03/2018, 11:30:21.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
27/03/2018, 11:33:28.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/03/2018, 11:33:28.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:33:28.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/03/2018, 11:33:29.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
27/03/2018, 11:33:31.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:33:31.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:33:31.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:33:31.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/03/2018, 11:35:46.400 [WARN] Failed to find node for hop #1 of our path. Discarding this circuit. 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (Operation timed out; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host 09A1AE88A78746AA9EC1BD5953E84F61CB763BCA at 195.154.156.231:9001) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.200 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.200 [WARN]  8 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host 21310F48066A4CAADEB2BFD324F0B38F8E1448D6 at 212.89.225.242:443) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  2 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host 88C3708A9D71ECEC1910B63C3FAA5BF60CD7E199 at 51.15.47.62:443) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] 14 connections have failed: 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host 78BC2254D3B31CD865F7682633AA438212132532 at 51.15.80.7:443) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host 327F5823438B8EC86EC33355C147D8455AB1C14B at 93.115.91.66:443) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] 16 connections have failed: 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host DBE82FA23B9FE3CB2462A6FCF5289DED3CBF4AEE at 138.201.169.12:443) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] 17 connections have failed: 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  6 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (DONE; DONE; count 16; recommendation warn; host 0ED0EA324C931CF41CB5272BFB1D015B3D5772A9 at 217.182.196.68:443) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] 19 connections have failed: 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  11 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  7 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (DONE; DONE; count 17; recommendation warn; host 15C5C5F5964F4ADA8D9CE26A0FE27C16D2B156E3 at 5.196.29.217:443) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN] 20 connections have failed: 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  11 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  8 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
27/03/2018, 11:36:07.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.`

Comment: Most likely they are blocking connections to the Tor network and a bridge would solve the problem. It's also possible Tor Browser needs to be told to use your school's HTTP(S) proxy in order to reach the Internet, if your school has one and blocks traffic that doesn't go through it.

Comment: Yes, it's possibly that, but I can't find out I way to do it. Could you point me in the right direction? I also can't find any bridges to use; I email bridges@torproject.org "get bridges" and they send an empty message back; the website it also blocked.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your school has some type of firewall that is blocking tor. With the way that the tor browser is designed now, you may want to go home and do what I'm about to suggest doing.

Step 1. Go home, and when you are on your home or uncesnored internet connection, connect directly to the tor network first. I will supply screenshots  below on what you should do:

EDIT: stack exchage would not allow me to post the screenshots as they were too big, you can find them at this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bqE0NeM49q_zn0ysvh7NP6o4sJleFsgP

When at home and  directly connected to tor, click the onion icon and click "tor network settings".

You will see three options, tor is censored in my country, I use a proxy to access the internet, and this computer goes through a firewall that only allows certain ports.

2. I would recommend checking the one that says "this computer goes through a firewall that only allows certain ports". This might not be a 100% necessary step for your schools firewall, but I would check it in case your school does have a firewall with a super restrictive port blocker; it will say ports 80, 443 which are two ports that need to be open to get a network connection.
3. Find out if your school uses local proxy settings to access the internet (if they have a proxy server on their network). If they do, check I use a proxy to access the internet and enter the same proxy setting they normally use in there (leave it unchecked if they don't use a proxy server).
4. Leave the port restriction option mentioned earlier checked, if you have both that checked and the proxy server information entered correctly, try connecting now. If it works then awesome. However it could be the actual tor network itself is blocked. If that's the case, check "tor is censored in my country" This will give you the option to use bridges, unlisted / disguised tor entry points, the point behind them is that because they aren't listed in the public relay list, you can still connect to them if the public tor network is blocked. Try using "select a bridge I know" and try them all and use the one that works. If they get blocked; find more and use the option "provide a bride I know and enter them." You say that the email you get back from tor is blocked; keep in mind the email has to be sent from an either Gmail or Yahoo email account (gmail.com or yahoo.com domain) Any other email service provider will not work. You can also go to bridges.torproject.org on your smartphone or something and find bridges there.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and easy to follow answer, This is really helpful! I'll make sure to try those settings when I have the opportunity, hopefully they should work.

Comment: Yeah man, unfortunately the newer tor browsers method of accessing those configuration options is a little bit sucky. But if you do all the things above you should have no problem configuring your tor browser to bypass their firewall.

Comment: Given that you checked this as the correct answer, I'll have to assume this worked :-). Glad to be of service.

Comment: Not sure why I checked it, but this doesn't work. My school blocks port 80 (So only 443 is open), so I think that is why Tor is not getting a connection. Fyi I tried your method lots of times, and tried using bridges, all of them to no avail. Also tried popular VPNs like Nord vpn to unblock the network, still no success.

Comment: It’s not likely port 80 is blocked, you wouldn’t be able to access most websites as http used port 80. Make sure you are entering the school proxy server information correctly and use pluggable transport bridges. Thx.

Comment: That is correct, we aren't allowed to view http sites, only secure https ones. The proxies and bridges are correct, and it still doesn't connect. I know they are correct because I checked at home.